# Highlight PrimeReact Datatable's Data using react-highlight-words

Tags: javascript, reactjs, primereact

I have PrimeReact DataTable with search/filter functionality. My main goal here is to highlight the text or data in DataTable that matches on the Search Input of the user.

I used [react-highlight-words](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-highlight-words) for the highlighting of data. Using the props `textToHighlight`, I can highlighted the text.

The Problem:

1. `textToHighlight` only accepts string and I don't have idea how to pass the component `DataTable` or its data in the props.

I tried the following:

1. I pass the `Input` state in `textToHighlight` props but unfortunately it prints the data outside the table.
2. I tried to put the `DataTable` component inside the `Highlighter` component, but the table doesn't render.

**Here's the image:**
[image]

**ThesisList.jsx**

```
  // Search Box
  const renderHeader = () => {
    return (
      <div className="flex justify-between">
        <Button
          className="p-button-outlined"
          icon="pi pi-filter-slash"
          label="Clear"
          onClick={clearFilter}
        />
        <span className="p-input-icon-left">
          <i className="pi pi-search" />
          <InputText
            placeholder="Search"
            value={globalFilterValue}
            onChange={onGlobalFilterChange}
          />
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  };

 // The function who checks if the input matches the Filters (check initFilter()).
  const onGlobalFilterChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;

    let _filter = { ...filters };
    _filter["global"].value = value;
    setFilters(_filter);
    setGlobalFilterValue(value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="p-4 w-full h-screen">
      //As you can see here I used the Input state
      <Highlighter
        searchWords={[globalFilterValue]}
        textToHighlight={globalFilterValue}
      />
      <DataTable>
        ...
      </DataTable>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each column in Primereact Data table takes a prop called `body` through which we can format the cells, so in your case, you can pass the `Highlighter` as the body for each column.

Here's an example with the title column.

```js
<Datatable>
  ...
   <Column 
       field="title"
       header="Title"
       body={(rowData) => (
          <Highlighter
             searchWords={[globalFilterValue]}
             textToHighlight={rowData.title}
          />
       )}
   />
  ...
</Datatable>
```

Comment: Its working sir, thank you. But how I can access the rowData."fieldName" because I loop my columns sir.

Comment: You can use ````rowData[fieldName]````

Comment: Thank you for this sir. I just want to add, error occurred because ```textToHighlight``` detected that ```rowData[fieldName]``` is a number so I added ```toString()``` to make it a string. Thank you again.